# Can't get jQuery dataTables ajax.reload() to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have set up a dataTable using the following code:

```
function setDataTable() {

    $("#mycontainer > div.box-body > table tfoot th").each(function() {
       var title = $("#mycontainer > div.box-body > table tfoot th").eq($(this).index()).text();
       $(this).html( '<input type="text" style="width: 60px;" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    });
    var mycontainer = $("#mycontainer > div.box-body > table").DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/myapp/rest/mycall",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "paging": false,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "myName" },
            { "data": "myNo" },
            { "data": "branch" },
            { "data": "branchType" }
        ]
    });
    mycontainer.columns().every(function(){
        var that = this;
        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
           that.search( this.value ).draw(); 
        });
    });
}
```

I am trying to trigger a refresh of the dataTable and had used the following code:

```
function refreshDataTable() {
    console.log("Refresh table");
    $("#mycontainer > div.box-body > table").DataTable().ajax.reload();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnRefreshDataTable").click(function(){
        refreshDataTable();
    });
}
```

But this doesn't seem to do jack to change the table in any way.

I had even tried to destroy the table using the following line but the table is still there:

```
$("#mycontainer > div.box-body > table").DataTable().destroy();
```

Maybe it's something obvious that's right in front of me but I simply don't see it right now. Would very much appreciate any pointers in the right direction, thanks!!